# Adding variable to a array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add parameters to a function in javascript, but it doesnt work somehow.

Can you let me know, how can I add them ?

I have a function like :

```
var foo = function () {
        var a = {
            "abc":"value1"
            "bcd":"value2"
        }
        return a;
    };
```

Now, I do this :

```
alert(data: [foo()]) // Actually I keep it in my function and **it works**
```

And I can see "abcd" and "bcd" with values.

But, Now I want to add a more variable (which is dynamic), how can I do that

I try this :

```
data:[foo() + {"cde":"value3"}] //doesnt work
data:[foo().push ({"cde"="value3"})] //doesnt work
```

How can I add a more variable to this array

Comment: Even if you are creating a C# application, if your question isn't related to C#, there's no benefit to tagging it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foo` is a function that returns an object not an array. So there isn't any `push` method. If you want to add a new property to the object that `foo` returns you can do so as below:

```
// keep a reference to the object that foo returns
var obj = foo();
obj["cde"] = "value3";
```

or using dot notation as

```
obj.cde = "value3";
```

```js
var foo = function () {
    var a = {
        "abc":"value1",
        "bcd":"value2"
    }
    return a;
};

var obj = foo();
obj["cde"] = "value3";

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try as below:

```
var x = foo();
x["newProp"] = 33;
```

Comment: Any reason they couldn't do `x.newProp = 33`?

Comment: @musicnothing Yes, that's also possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rest parameter`, `spread element` `Object.assign()` to return `a` if no parameters passed, else set passed parameters to `a` object

```js
var foo = function foo(...props) {
  var a = {
    "abc": "value1",
    "bcd": "value2"
  }
  // if no parameters passed return `a`
  if (!props.length) return a;
  // else set passed property at `a` object
  return Object.assign(a, ...props);
};

var a = foo();
var b = foo({"cde":"value3"});
console.log(a, b);
```